# jsonresultadapter : nested partial entities

Tags: breeze

I have an issue, in my breeze metadatastore I have an entity `A` with a `navigationProperty` to entity `B`

I would like to prime data getting only few important properties of `A` and few ones for `B` by using the breeze query projection manager like this:

```
var eq = EntityQuery.from("A").**select("PROP1,PROP2,B.PROP1")**;
    return EntityManager.executeQuery(eq)
```

I'm getting it in a plain object `{PROP1 : VALUE, PROP2 : VALUE, B_PROP1 : VALUE}` that I'd like to turn in a partial cached entity of type `A` with a nested entity `B`:

```
{
PROP1 : VALUE, 
PROP2 : VALUE, 
B : {PROP1 : VALUE}
}
```

How can I achieve it by using the `jsonresultadapter`?

I have no issue working at first level, but going deeper I have troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the method visitNode, by getting parseContext.EntityManger I was able to create a new entity B and add it as property in the root of node parameter